# Apache HTTP Server docs on public_html and the series of steps taken when a client connects

Tags: apache, web, apache2

What does the apache server do when a client visits a website which is hosted on it. i.e what folder does it access and what is the default page it tries to serve? What is the folder structure it contains. Does it maps the folders?

What links can answer such a kind of questions. I have searched www.apache.org but most of the docs say how to install start and the like, I have experience in socket programming and in general programming. What are the series of steps apache takes when a client connects to its port number 80.

Answer (score 0):

Basically apache can work as "one domain" server or multiple (virtualhost) hosting server.

Speaking of apache 2, server virtual hosts are configured in

```
path_to_apache_config/sites-available/domain_config
path_to_apache_config/sites-enabled/link_to_domain_config
```

In each definition of virtual host, which could be just your own local host, there are plenty of settings which can be applied and alter behavior for each site you are hosting.

When a client connects to a server, apache checks whether there is a  definition that matches domain in user request. If that's positive, it read's the configuration which points to the website files folder with directive

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/your_site_folder
```

From that part you are free to use any folder structure you want. If you use mod_userdir, which enables to host webpages for users who are known to the system, it will point them to

```
/home/john/public_html
```

And from that point on, it is the same as mentioned above.

What pages the server can serve is a matter of installed libraries. Default settings are that apache servers html pages. If you install php, cgi (executables) support, you can server other appropriate pages.

The first thing server looks for is a - index.(html|php|...). If it does not exist, it tries to list the content of that directory (depends only on configuration if it's allowed), otherwise it returns "Forbidden..." status.

Comment: Please point to the docs in which these information is specified.

Comment: Apache 2 installing, configuring, available directives and several configuration examples can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/). It's official documentation, which should more or less cover your topic.